# Error with recursion

Tags: odoo-8, odoo, odoo-10

I'm getting RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded error and it's because of the line "'account_id','not in'"  what can i do about it?

```
            @api.multi
            def to_invoice(self):
                    pos_order = self.env['pos.order'].search([('id','=',self._context.get('active_id'))])

                for line in pos_order.lines:
                domain3 = [
                    ('move_id', '=', pos_order.account_move.id),
                    ('credit', '=', pos_order.amount_tax),
                    ('account_id','not in', [pos_order.lines.tax_ids_after_fiscal_position, pos_order.lines.product_id.categ_id.property_account_income_categ_id])
            ]
                    if pos_order.amount_tax > 0:
                        move_line = 
self.env['account.move.line'].search(domain3)
                        print move_line
                    move_line[0].unlink()
```

Comment: Do you know how maximum recursion occurs?

Comment: no, i just do know it occurs when it hits                     ('account_id','not in', [pos_order.lines.tax_ids_after_fiscal_position, pos_order.lines.product_id.categ_id.property_account_income_categ_id]) line

Comment: It causes because of the loop which calculates so many times for account_id. Better add a condition like, once if your value is achieved, put a break at the end of the condition, so that the loop will stop once the correct value is achieved.

Comment: yeh i tried to put break in the end but didn't help. can you give example how this code should look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line should be

> ('account_id','not in', [line.tax_ids_after_fiscal_position.id,
>   line.product_id.categ_id.property_account_income_categ_id.id])

Comment: Which line are you speaking about?

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
@api.multi

def to_invoice(self):
   pos_order = self.env['pos.order'].search([('id','=',self._context.get('active_id'))])

   for line in pos_order.lines:
       domain3 = [
                    ('move_id', '=', pos_order.account_move.id),
                    ('credit', '=', pos_order.amount_tax),
                    ('account_id','not in', [pos_order.lines.tax_ids_after_fiscal_position, pos_order.lines.product_id.categ_id.property_account_income_categ_id])
                 ]
        if pos_order.amount_tax > 0:
           move_line = self.env['account.move.line'].search(domain3)
           print move_line
           move_line[0].unlink()
        break
```